# Can I use a Render Function inside a .vue File

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am looking to dynamically set the html tags for components.  For instance:

```
  components: {
    test: {
      props: ['tag', 'attributes'],
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement(this.tag || 'div', {attrs: this.attributes || {}}, this.$slots.default);
      }
    }
  }
```

I can then use code like this in an html file:

```
<test tag="a" :attributes="{href:'http://www.google.com'}">a tag content</test>
<test tag="p">p tag content</test>
```

Now, what I want to do is split up my components using something like Vue Loader.  Basically, I want to split up my different components into different files and then import them using a main.js file.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
// components/test.js 
export default {
  components: {
    test: {
      props: ['tag', 'attributes'],
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement(this.tag || 'div', {attrs: this.attributes || {}}, this.$slots.default);
      }
    }
  }
}

// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'  // don't think this is relevant, but it's there
import Test from './components/Test.js'
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        Test
    }
})
```

This does NOT work thought.

Any idea how to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Is the filename lower case test.js and you are importing capitalized Test.js?

Comment: The file name was upper case - Test.js.  I just changed it to lowercase and imported it as lower case.  No change (i.e., same problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structure test.js like this:

```
export default {
      props: ['tag', 'attributes'],
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement(this.tag || 'div', {attrs: this.attributes || {}}, this.$slots.default);
      }
}
```